# DOM Testing Library: Selecting a button when form header has the same text content?

Tags: javascript, testing, react-testing-library

I am using DOM Testing Library, not React Testing Library, but there was no tag for the former so I used the latter because that seems to be the closest match. Hope that's ok.

I have an authentication form whose submit button contains the text "Log in", and the page also contains a heading with the same text content:

[image: screen shot of admin login form showing heading "Admin log in" and submit button with text "log in"]

As seen in the screen shot, I've actually changed the heading to say "Admin Log In" because this (at least temporarily) solves the problem.

I've written my test as follows:

```js
import { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } from '@testing-library/testcafe';

const testHostname = process.env.TEST_HOST || 'https://redacted-qa-server';

fixture`Admin Auth`.page`${testHostname}/admin/`;

test('authentication works for a known account', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(getByPlaceholderText('E-mail address'), username)
        .typeText(getByPlaceholderText('Your password'), password)
        .click(getByText('Log in'));

    const location = await t.eval(() => window.location);
    await t.expect(location.pathname).notContains('/login');
});
```

> It's worth mentioning that both the heading and the submit button are currently using CSS to style the text as all-caps, but both are coded using the case "Log in".

By changing the heading content to include "Admin" and using an exact-match precision in `getByText`, this test can pass. But what if I don't want to include the "Admin" prefix in the heading?

I know that I can use a regex match like `getByText(/^log in$/i)` to be case insensitive but not allow substrings, but that doesn't solve for the "I don't want to keep the admin prefix" problem.

I know that I can use `getAllByText` to get an array of the matches and can simply know which one is the one I want to click... but that seems to go against the spirit of DOM Testing Library. Is there a blessed solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getByText(/log in/i, {selector: 'button'})` to select the login button.

You may also be interested in [the upcoming `name` option](https://github.com/eps1lon/testing-library-docs/blob/feat/byRole/name-filter/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries.md#byrole) for `*ByRole` queries. Once that's released, you could also do: `getByRole('button', {name: /log in/i})`.

Given the choice between the too, I think I'd prefer `getByText`. Good luck!